# How to receive input from a segmented control

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to receive the user selection from a segmented control and then save it to NSUserDefaults, i.e., if the first segment is selected then it saves the int "1" to NSUserDefaults, but if the  second segment is selected then it saves the int "2" to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Its iOS so what is an alternative to binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a binding.  Bind the selected index of the control to the shared user defaults controller, and set the model key path to the preference key you want to use.

**Edit to add**: I see that you didn't specify Mac or iOS.  If it's Mac, binding is definitely the easy way, whereas binding is not available on iOS.

The fact that segmented control values start at 0 is unimportant.  You could bind selected tag rather than selected index, and then use any tag values you want.

Comment: Alright. So I've tested everything and what I've discovered is that my problem is actually this. I have 2 views, main view and flipSideView. One view only needs to read from the nsuserdocuments while the other needs to read and write from it, but in my code I was allocating 2 separate nsuserdocuments under the same name; 1 for each view, which isnt right. So how do I allocate it in one and connect to it in the other?

Comment: It sounds like you now have a question that has nothing whatsoever to do with your original question, so I think you should post a new question.

Answer (score 8):

```
- (IBAction)totalAction:(id)sender {
    toggleNav = sender; // this is your segmented control 
    if ([toggleNav selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        NSlog(@"i am here");
    } else if ([toggleNav selectedSegmentIndex] == 1) {
        NSlog(@"i am here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't listen to the guy above. First thing you should know is that UISegmentedControl starts at 0. So the first bar is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2, etc...
If you want to start at zero, just add one to the integer once you get the value. (look below)
To get its value when its changed, hook up an IBAction method and connect that to your UISegmentedControl. Make the action happen with valueChanged, not with touchUpInside. Then within your IBAction method, let's say it is called "theMethod", use this code.

```
-(IBAction)theMethod {
int theInteger;
theInteger = [segmentedController selectedSegmentIndex];//segmentedController is the name of your UISegmentedController.
//theInteger ++; //adds 1 to the integer so as to start the numbering at 1 instead of 0 like I have explained up above.
```

Then, you can go about saving the integer with your NSUserDefaults.

Note, you will need to convert your integer into an NSNumber if you wish to save it, because you can't save integers or variables, you can only save objects.
For this I would use the following:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:theInteger];
```

Answer (score 1):

if　you are working with iOS, you can add following to the segmentedcontrol

```
           [yourSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

where in your valueChanged method, you update UserDefaults.
Note the colon after valueChanged. You don't need it if valueChanged does not have a parameter.